# Why can't I render this simple list with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

This very simple app is not working. My list is not showing up. Why? I must be missing something important about how Meteor works.

**recipes.html**

```html
<body>
    <h3>Recipes</h3>
    {{> recipes}}
</body>

<template name="recipes">
    <ul>
        {{#each recipes}}
            <li>{{name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

**recipes.coffee**

```coffeescript
Recipes = new Meteor.Collection("recipes")

if Meteor.is_client
    Meteor.startup ->
        Meteor.autosubscribe(->
            Meteor.subscribe('recipes')
        )

        # THIS IS NOT WORKING
        Template.recipes.recipes ->
            return Recipes.find()

if Meteor.is_server
    Meteor.startup ->
        if Recipes.find().count() == 0
            data = [
               name: "Chocolate Chip Cookies"
            ,
               name: "Spring Rolls"
           ]

        for item in data
            Recipes.insert(item)

    Meteor.publish('recipes', ->
        return Recipes.find()
    )
```

**error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (data) {
      var getHtml = function() {
        return raw_func(data, {
          helpers: partial,
          partials: Meteor._partials
        });
      };

      var react_data = { events: (name ? Template[name].events : {}),
                         event_data: data,
                         template_name: name };

      return Meteor.ui.chunk(getHtml, react_data);
    } has no method 'recipes'
```

I've tried this with autopublish and without. What am I not understanding here?

**Edit:**

I posted the wrong code before, as Jasd pointed out. The code as it is now is the code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
Template.recipes.recipes = ->
    return Recipes.find()
```

because 1.) you *assign* the function to `Template.recipes.recipes` and 2.) you iterate through list `recipes` of template `recipes`. You don't need to return another object with key `recipes` I guess.

Comment: You're right, but that was just a mistake I made when posting the code. I've edited the question to show only the code in question now.

Comment: What about the `=`? I think you need it. That was meant in 1.)

Answer (score 0):

should be this -

```
Recipes = new Meteor.Collection("recipes")

if Meteor.is_client
    Meteor.startup ->
        Meteor.autosubscribe(->
            Meteor.subscribe('recipes')
        )

    # OUTINDENT
    # ASSIGNMEMT, NOT FUNCTION CALL
    Template.recipes.recipes = ->
        return Recipes.find()

if Meteor.is_server
    Meteor.startup ->
        if Recipes.find().count() == 0
            data = [
               name: "Chocolate Chip Cookies"
            ,
               name: "Spring Rolls"
            ]

            # INDENT
            for item in data
                Recipes.insert(item)

    Meteor.publish('recipes', ->
        return Recipes.find()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make sure you assign to `Template.recipe.recipes` (could be a typo in your qn)

   ```
   Template.recipes.recipes = ->
     return Recipes.find()
   ```
2. You don't want to do that in `Meteor.startup`, that runs after the template has been evaluated (and so it'll think `Template.recipe.recipes` is `null`) -- move it to the top level of your `is_client` block and I think it'll be fine.